# Suspend/Resume MDBs deployed in Weblogic 12c using WLST script

Tags: weblogic, wlst

In weblogic 12c, I have deployed EAR file that contains couple of JAR and WAR files

I want to list down only the deployed MDBs and Suspend/Resume MDB using WLST

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer. Information on EJB deployments can be found under serverRuntime and same can be enabled and disabled using suspend and resume property

```
connect(…)
serverRuntime()
cd(ApplicationRuntimes/<appname>/ComponentRuntimes/EJBRuntimes/<MDBName>)
```

## To suspend MDB

cmo.suspend()

## To RESUME MDB

cmo.resume()